# Group chat to private chat Whatsapp like functionality

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a mobile application using firebase and android studio. In that I like to have a Whatsapp sort of functionality to have an interconnection between group chat and private chat . In whatsapp group messages if we click the name of the messenger (please note that in the name , not on the message, see the attached picture), a popup opens and there will an option to do private message to that particular person. In a similar way I like to do private message from group chat in my app. I think they had used 'onClickListenerRecyclerAdapter' for displaying the group messages,  but I am not having an idea how they have done only for the name. If some one know how to connect group chat to private chat please help  .  [image]

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, the message from `Veena` is displaying:

- Veena's name.
- The message timestamp.
- The message content, 'Hi'.

But there are plenty of other properties, as you know of course, being stored in this message object, one of them is Veena's ID.

The popup menu, will be an extension to the message object, which inherits the properties of the message for the callback after pressing the message itself. It'll also show Veena's name, but selecting it, will/should take you to the chat which corresponds to Veena's ID.

Comment: @Huthifa Muayyad can you able to tell me how to do that using andorid studio and firebase